# Representing particular sets of complex numbers

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, plane-geometry

I am supposed to represent the following sets:

> \begin{align}A&=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:\Re(2z+iz)<0<\Im(z^2)\}, \\ B&=\{w\in\mathbb{C}:w=z^2, z\in A\}, \\ C&=\{u\in\mathbb{C}:u=1/z, z\in A\}.\end{align}

I think I have handled the first one. Writing $z$ in algebraic form, I derived $$A=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R^2}:y>2x, xy>0\},$$ so it should individuate the portion of the complex plane enclosed between the line $y=2x$, the positive $y$-semiaxes  and the negative $x$-semiaxis.

I am lost with the other two. Sticking to $z=x+iy$ led me to $B=\{(s,t)\in\mathbb{R^2}:s+it=x^2-y^2+2ixy\}.$ Here's my problem: I can see that the ordinates of the points of $B$ lie on the upper half-plane, but how can the abscissas describe a function of two variables? I guess I have no clue about the third set, after using again $z=x+iy$.

I tried writing $z$ in the other forms but it didn't help me, what am I missing?

Comment: Once you have found $A$ and noted that it consists of a set of rays starting at $0$, a natural way to proceed is to rewrite $A$ in polar coordinates.

Comment: @GregMartin Thank you too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint** The key observation is that the set $A$ is a union of two open sectors with vertex at $0$, which suggests describing them in polar form. For example, the sector in the first quadrant is
$$\left\{ r e^{i \theta} : r > 0, \arctan 2 < \theta < \tfrac{\pi}{2} \right\} .$$

This is useful for describing $B$, $C$, as those sets are described in terms of powers of elements of $A$ and the expression of (integer) powers is especially simple in polar form: $(r e^{i \theta})^k = r^k e^{i (k \theta)}$.

Comment: Ok, I see it was fairly easy, thank you.

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad you found it helpful.